# how to get latitude and longitude of my current location using JAVA

Tags: geolocation, latitude-longitude

I want to get latitude and longitude using Java. I need some JAVA API , which can be used to get current latitude and longitude. There is option in Google Geo-location API in which we can get latitude and longitude by setting location name , but i need current location without knowing the name of location.

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a program that doesn't connect to the internet this is impossible from what you describe.

If you do, however, there are some location via IP options available.

http://skyhookwireless.com/location-technology/ is one.

Comment: Program will be connected to Internet that is sure , But I am looking any open source API . Does Google Geo-location API has facility to find current position and latitude , longitude in Java.

Comment: How to get current location latitude and longitude in java?without passing any input. If possible please let me know.